# Solr segment merge policy not working

Tags: solrcloud, segments

I am using solr-5.4.0 and my current solrconfig.xml settings are

```
<ramBufferSizeMB>300</ramBufferSizeMB>
<!-- <maxBufferedDocs>1000</maxBufferedDocs> -->
<!--
    <mergePolicy class="org.apache.lucene.index.TieredMergePolicy">
      <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
      <int name="segmentsPerTier">10</int>
      <double name="noCFSRatio">0.1</double>
    </mergePolicy>
  -->

<mergeFactor>5</mergeFactor>
```

I had a couple of questions regarding this.
1) According to this my segment should merge into single when there number reaches 5, but this does not happen(currently I have 19 segments in my collection that has one shard and 2 replicas). Why?

2) Is there something that I am missing here maybe a parameter?

Thanks.